# Using Ninject in WebAPI2 - Error: Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor

Tags: c#, ninject, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to make binding and dependency injection using Ninject in WebAPI2 application, but apparently I've did something wrong.

I want to create my code according to Repository pattern so I have an interface with simple definition of only method I need:

```
public interface IAccountRepository
{
    AccountsOverview GetUserAccounts(HttpActionContext actionContext);
}
```

This is my class that implements IAccountRepository interface:

```
    public class AccountRepository : IAccountRepository
    {
        private readonly MockStorage mockStorage;

        public AccountRepository(MockStorage mockStorage)
        {
            this.mockStorage = mockStorage;
        }

        public AccountsOverview GetUserAccounts(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            AccountsOverview accountsOverview = new AccountsOverview();
            var userName = actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity.Name;
            Dictionary<string, List<Account>> accountsData = new Dictionary<string, List<Account>>();
            accountsData = MockStorage.GetAccountData();
            List<Account> userAccounts = accountsData.SelectMany(u => u.Value).ToList();

            accountsOverview.Accounts = userAccounts;
            accountsOverview.CurrentAccountsTotal = userAccounts.Where(a => a.AccountType == "Current card").Sum(a => a.Balance);
            accountsOverview.SavingAccountsTotal = userAccounts.Where(a => a.AccountType == "Saving card").Sum(a => a.Balance);
            accountsOverview.SavingAccountsTotalCurrency = "euro";
            accountsOverview.CurrentAccountsTotalCurrency = "euro";

            return accountsOverview;
        }
   }
```

MockStorage.cs is simple class that contains some simple test data it has one method GetAccountData, which returns Dictionary type.

```
public static Dictionary<string, List<Account>> GetAccountData()
{
      Dictionary<string, List<Account>> dictionaries = new Dictionary<string, List<Account>>();

      List<Account> NMoAccounts = new List<Account>(){
                                  new Account {AccountName="Credit card 1", AccountNumber=1234567890, AccountType="Credit card", AvailableBalance=234.4m, Balance=432.64m, Currency="euro", InterestRate=1.5m},
                                  new Account {AccountName="Credit card 3", AccountNumber=1357924680, AccountType="Credit card", AvailableBalance=24.06m, Balance=-32.123m, Currency="euro", InterestRate=1.5m},
                                  new Account {AccountName="Current card 10", AccountNumber=1357924680, AccountType="Current card", AvailableBalance=1.8m, Balance=2.3m, Currency="euro", InterestRate=1.5m},
                                  new Account {AccountName="Credit card 5", AccountNumber=1357924680, AccountType="Credit card", AvailableBalance=31.4m, Balance=-132.123m, Currency="euro", InterestRate=1.5m} 
                                  };

      dictionaries.Add("n.mosorinski", NMoAccounts);
      return dictionaries;
}
```

I've made web api controller that consumes this:

```
public class BankAccountController : ApiController
{
    private IAccountRepository _accountsRepo;

    public BankAccountController(IAccountRepository accountsRepo)
    {
        this._accountsRepo = accountsRepo;  
    }

    [Route("accounts")]
    public AccountsOverview GetAccounts()
    {
        return _accountsRepo.GetUserAccounts(this.ActionContext);  
    }
}
```

In my Startup.cs class I've define Ninject kernel as follow:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

        var webApiConfiguration = new HttpConfiguration();

        ConfigureOAuth(app);

        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.UseWebApi(config);
        app.UseNinjectMiddleware(CreateKernel);
        app.UseNinjectWebApi(webApiConfiguration);

    }
    private static StandardKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Bind<MockStorage>().To<MockStorage>().InSingletonScope();
        kernel.Bind<IAccountRepository>().To<BankingPoCMobileBackend.Repository.Mock.AccountRepository>();
        return kernel;
    }
}
```

When I try to invoke GetAccounts method from BankAccountsController I get follow error:

```
{
    "message": "An error has occurred.",
    "exceptionMessage": "An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'BankAccountController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.",
    "exceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
    "stackTrace": "   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage request)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()",
    "innerException": {
        "message": "An error has occurred.",
        "exceptionMessage": "Type 'BankingPoCMobileBackend.Controllers.BankAccountController' does not have a default constructor",
        "exceptionType": "System.ArgumentException",
        "stackTrace": "   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(Type type)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Internal.TypeActivator.Create[TBase](Type instanceType)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)"
    }
}
```

Did anyone had this kind of problem? I guess I've didn't do something right with Ninject, but I don't have an idea what it could be. Did someone experienced similar or same problem perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what version of Ninject.Web.WebApi you are using, but I found that when I was using version 3.2.4.0 I would have this exact problem.

Once I rolled back to version 3.2.1.0 the problem went away.  I'm not sure which version the issue was introduced in, or what is causing it, but this fixed the issue for me.